# How do you uninstall the package manager "pip", if installed from source?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, system-administration

I was unaware that pip could be installed via my operating system's package manager, so I compiled and installed pip via source with the following command:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

I would like to uninstall pip, and instead install it from my operating system's package manager. How would I go about completely undoing the work of the installation script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That way you haven't installed pip, you installed just the `easy_install` i.e. `setuptools`.

First you should remove all the packages you installed with `easy_install` using (see [uninstall](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#uninstalling-packages)):

```
easy_install -m PackageName
```

This includes `pip` if you installed it using `easy_install pip`.

After this you remove the `setuptools` following the instructions from [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/faq.html#what-if-i-have-setuptools-installed):

> If setuptools package is found in your global site-packages directory,
>   you may safely remove the following file/directory:

```
setuptools-*.egg
```

> If setuptools is installed in some other location such as the user site directory
>   (eg: ~/.local, ~/Library/Python or %APPDATA%), then you may safely remove the
>   following files:

```
pkg_resources.py
easy_install.py
setuptools/
setuptools-*.egg-info/
```

Comment: What if you install pip using the `get-pip.py` file or something?

Comment: @Viktor Kerkez, I am not able to uninstall pip. I used easy_install pip command. Now I wanted to downgrade pip version. how to unistall pip?

Answer (score 80):

`pip uninstall pip` will work

Comment: Not if your pip is corrupted!

Comment: I destroyed the stones with the stones.  Upvoting

Answer (score 8):

If you installed pip like this:

```
 - sudo apt install python-pip
 - sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Uninstall them like this:

```
 - sudo apt remove python-pip
 - sudo apt remove python3-pip
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using above command but it was not working. This command worked for me:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```