# Unable to properly install pip3 for python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am having trouble properly installing pip3 for python3. It appears that I have installed pip and pip3 successfully.

```
whereis pip
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.7

whereis pip3
pip3: /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip3.7 /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
```

What makes me curious is when I type:

```
pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /home/fmd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

This gives proper result but when I do the same for pip3 I this:

```
pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

I have referred
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
[How do you uninstall the package manager "pip", if installed from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546321/how-do-you-uninstall-the-package-manager-pip-if-installed-from-source). And tried to uninstalling and reinstalling pip3 but it dosent seem to work I get the same error as above. How do I remove this error?

My system is:

```
> NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)" ID=ubuntu
> ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS" VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad seems like I installed pip3.7 binary

```
pip3.7 --version
pip 19.0.3 from /home/fmd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I would install python3 dependencies using pip3.7 rather than pip3

for example `pip3.7 install numpy` and so on.